# Как получить московское время независимо от установленного часового пояса на устройстве?

Tags: swift, дата, ios10

Каким образом можно получить именно московское время независимо от установленного часового пояса установленного на устройстве пользователя?

```
private func isItOpenNow() -> Bool? {
    let date = Date()
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour], from: date)

    // TODO: здесь нужно вытаскивать именно московское время

    if let weekday = components.weekday, let hour = components.hour {
        if weekday != 2 { // Пн - выходной
            if hour >= 10 && hour < 18 {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Именно для этой ситуации и существует [`dateComponents(in:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293477-datecomponents). Тайм-зону можно получить как `TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Moscow")`.

Comment: прежде чем вносить правки в чужие сообщения - обсудите их с автором поста. возможно также что вам просто нужно дать ещё один ответ, либо задать новый вопрос, либо просто оставить комментарий под ответом.

Comment: я вроде не тупо внес правку в чужое сообщение, а отправил ее на утверждение автору с комментарием, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именно для этой ситуации и существует [`dateComponents(in:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293477-datecomponents):

```
private func isItOpenNow() -> Bool? {
    let date = Date()
    guard let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Moscow") else { return nil } // получаем московскую таймзону, в реальном коде можно не делать `return` и использовать что-нибудь по умолчанию

    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: date) // тут мы получаем компоненты в нужной таймзоне

    // NOTE: здесь у нас московское время

    if let weekday = components.weekday, let hour = components.hour {
        if weekday != 2 { // Пн - выходной 
            if hour >= 10 && hour < 18 {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    return nil
}
```

И всё можно сделать с `DateComponents`, не прибегая к перегону даты в строку через форматер (который там создается при каждом вызове функции).

Answer (score 2):

Может так?

```
func currentMoscowTime() -> Date {
  let currenUTC = Date()
  let moscowHourShiftInSeconds: Double = 3 * 60 * 60 // Московский сдвиг 3 часа в секундах
  return currenUTC.addingTimeInterval(moscowHourShiftInSeconds)
}
```

Comment: `NSDate() as Date` — **не надо** так делать, у `Date` есть свой собственный конструктор, почему бы его не использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Переписал этот метод таким образом:

```
private func isItOpenNow() -> Bool? {
    let date = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    if let timeZoneAbbreviation = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary["MSD"] { // NOTE: здесь нужно вытаскивать именно московское время
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timeZoneAbbreviation)
    } else {
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 60 * 60 * 3)
    }

    // http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H"
    let hourString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "c" // NOTE: 1-7 - Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat
    let weekdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    if let weekday = Int(weekdayString), let hour = Int(hourString) {
        if weekday != 2 { // Пн - выходной
            if hour >= 10 && hour < 18 {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    return nil
}
```

т.е. вместо `Calendar.current.dateComponents` можно использовать `DateFormatter` настроенный на нужный часовой пояс

Comment: Все же используйте не жёстко забитый +03 во временной зоне, а идентификатор, для Москвы это "Europe/Moscow".